# if Column A cell matches Column B cell, display column C value of same row as column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

if Column A cell matches Column B cell, display column C value of same row as column B

ColumnA in first excel file

```
liu.weio@xy.com
tonny@ab.com
wong@ab.com
might@ab.com
daniel@ab.com.br
user@ab.com.br
random@ab.com
Any@ab.com
```

ColumnB, ColumnC in second excel file

```
liu.weio@xy.com, US
tonny@ab.com, FR
wong@ab.com, IN
might@ab.com, JP
daniel@ab.com.br, CH
user@ab.com.br, AU
random@ab.com, RU
Any@ab.com, DE
extra@ab.com, PL
EXTRA1@av.com, RU
```

Expected result in first excel as Column A and Column B

```
liu.weio@xy.com, US
tonny@ab.com, FR
wong@ab.com, IN
might@ab.com, JP
daniel@ab.com.br, CH
user@ab.com.br, AU
random@ab.com, RU
Any@ab.com, DE
```

I tried with vlookup but not working with 3 columns

Comment: Column B is represented by the e-mails and column C by the countries abbreviations?

Comment: **yes** @Flaw98

Comment: If it's what you want, try to use this kind of formula `=IF(B1=A1;A1 & "," & " " & C1;"")`, it will leave a blank space where the conditions are not met. You will have to use refferences in order to use another Excel files.

Comment: thank you I figured it out :)

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;'details.xlxs'!$B:$B:'details.xlxs'!$C:$C;2;FALSE); "Not Found")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`=IF(A1<>"",IF(A1=LEFT(B1,LEN(A1)),B1,""),"")`

[image]

Comment: thank you, I figured it out :) =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;'details.xlxs'!$B:$B:'details.xlxs'!$C:$C;2;FALSE); "Not Found")